# OpenCV Sift - keypoints detects centroid of object?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, fiducial-markers

I am trying to find centroid of circular shape with the help of OpenCV Sift for my project.

[image: Test Image]

After finding centroid try to fit a encoding ring to detect type of marker. The SIFT algorithm is the best for my project, since it is scalar and rotation invariant. It seems to detect the keypoint of centroid of object and i am trying to get the coordinates of it.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

def findSift(img, gray, draw=True):
    sift = cv2.SIFT_create(10)
    kp = sift.detect(gray, None)
    if draw:
        cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, img)
    kp_coordinates = cv2.KeyPoint_convert(kp)
    return kp_coordinates 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    img = cv2.imread('Test.jpg')
    print(img.shape[:2])
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    Array_Cooridinates = findSift(img,gray)
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

```
Image Resolution: (849, 734)
Array of coordinates of keypoints detected:
[[346.20126 385.5532 ]
 [366.1102  217.0911 ]
 [366.1102  217.0911 ]
 [482.2291  451.484  ]
 [482.2291  451.484  ]
 [468.70483 303.86118]
 [468.70483 303.86118]
 [385.93945 296.0943 ]
 [417.37436 445.36234]
 [441.80768 377.35934]]
```

If someone have any reference to my problem, feel free to post it so i can do more research about it.

Thanks for any help here!
Have a nice day.

Comment: I don't think feature descriptors like SIFT will work for finding *fiducials*. SimpleBlobDetector with a filter on circularity should suffice to find the center circle... but then you have to filter all circular blobs to find those that have those bits encoded around them. -- what can you tell us about that fiducial? names, brands, publications, anything... I found this: https://www.falcon.de/falcon/en/marker_en.htm and you should have led your whole question with that, rather than asking how an ad hoc guess at a solution can me forced to work

Comment: if you need technical info, you oughta track down these people: https://www.hexagonmi.com/about-us/about-hexagon-manufacturing-intelligence/our-history/aicon-3d-systems-history https://www.hexagonmi.com/about-us/about-hexagon-manufacturing-intelligence/our-history/aicon-3d-systems-history

Comment: random paper describing a little about the code on these things: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Examples-of-Photomodeler-Scanner-O-and-AICON-3D-O-landmarks-a-Non-coded-landmarks-b_fig2_230612871 -- please review [ask]. research is your responsibility.